# Ruby output array each element with new line with indent

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have `array = [1,2,3,4,5]`

```
array.each do |e|
 ...
end
```

so i need to output it like

```
1
 2
  3
  4
  5
```

How can i do it?( how to output it particular order )

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @sawa question is how to output it particular order

Comment: Why aren't 4 and 5 indented?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev because i need exactly that output 4,5 under 3 without indent

Comment: Well, what have you tried, then?

Comment: i didn't try anything because i have no idea how it can be done. So i asked here .. :(

Comment: Well, the basic idea of indenting is printing some spaces. So you print `1`, then on the next line you print one space (`' '`) and _then_ `2`. Use that unknown-to-us logic for determining number of spaces to be printed and use it on all the other lines.

Comment: @Sergio, I've never seen the point of asking what the OP has tried, though I know it's routinely asked by many SO members. 50% of time it's for the reason this OP gave and 45% of time the OP responds by editing to provide nightmare-inducing code. IMO, whether and how we answer the question should not depend on the amount of effort the OP has expended. For one, our answers are not just for the benefit of the OP.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: I couldn't help myself. This question looks like no effort whatsoever was spent on producing it. Also I don't see how this is useful to future visitors (given the current state, anyway) so I refrained from posting own answer.

Comment: @xxx: I suggest you [re-]visit [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you've got an `array` of int from 1 to `array.length` and you would like to print the first `n` element indented by 0 to `n - 1` whitespaces and then go down in column.

For instance, with `n = 3` and `array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` the output will be

```
1     # 0     whitespaces
 2    # 1     whitespace
  3   # n - 1 whitespaces
  4   # n - 1 whitespaces
  5   # n - 1 whitespaces
```

The code that prints that sequence is

```
arr.each { |e| puts ( (e <= n ? " " * (e - 1) : " " * (n - 1)) + e.to_s ) }
```

assuming `n > 0`.

Answer (score 0):

Might as well pile on:

```
array = [1,2,3,4,5]
#array.map(&:to_s).each_with_index { |value, index| puts value.rjust(index < 3 ? index+1 : 4) }
array.each_with_index { |value, index| puts value.to_s.rjust(index < 3 ? index+1 : 4) }
```

Comment: Why do you do `map(&:to_s)` first when you could just do `value.to_s.rjust` in the `each_with_index` block?

Comment: Same difference, I suppose.

Comment: I think that iterating over a data structure once is better than iterating over it twice.

Comment: How about them apples?